# GCP Terraform: Grant Cloud run container access to a secret as environmental variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'd like to setup a secret in Google Cloud using terraform. I'd then like the cloudrun instance that I setup using Terraform to access this secret through an environmental variable.

Is this doable in terraform?

The secret will be manually set from the console at a later stage.

Comment: You might like to create a secret in advance (however you don't need to provide a value at this point), then (in terraform) grant the relevant access permissions (IAM role) to the service account, which is going to be used by the Cloud Run job, so the secret can be accessible from inside the Cloud Run code. Depending on your situation/context/requirements, you also might like to think about Private Google Access or/and Private Service Connect for handling outgoing Cloud Run requests.

Comment: Yeah, I see this as one way forward. Though It should be possible to set it as an environmental variable according to this: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/secrets I'd like to do the same in terraform if possible

Comment: When you deploy a Cloud Run service using https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_v2_service - there is an `env -> value_source -> secret_key_ref` block. The later is a name of a secret in a Cloud Secret Manager - https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_v2_service#nested_secret_key_ref  Do you think it might be possible to use that, in your case?

Comment: It's possible with Terraform, but the secret must use before Cloud Run deployment (even if the secret is not created by Terraform, you can use it as a resource)